# near "."; syntax error using JOIN in UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, dbeaver

Using SQLite 3.39.3 in DBeaver I am trying :

```
UPDATE Tbl_RawDataPART 
SET p.MessageClean = w.Vertaling, p.GedetecteerdeTaal = w.Taal
FROM Tbl_RawDataPART as p
INNER JOIN Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen as w ON p.message = w.Woord 
WHERE p.GedetecteerdeTaal  Is Null
```

I get :

> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "."; syntax error)

The same query in Microsoft Access works:

```
UPDATE Tbl_RawDataPART INNER JOIN Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen 
ON Tbl_RawDataPART.message = Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen.Woord 
SET Tbl_RawDataPART.MessageClean = [Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen]![Vertaling], Tbl_RawDataPART.GedetecteerdeTaal = [Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen]![Taal]
WHERE (((Tbl_RawDataPART.GedetecteerdeTaal) Is Null));
```

A `SELECT` in DBeaver works:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Tbl_RawDataPART as p
    INNER JOIN Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen as w ON p.message = w.Woord 
    WHERE p.GedetecteerdeTaal  Is Null
```

If I do `UPDATE` I get the same error:

```
UPDATE Tbl_RawDataPART 
SET p.MessageClean = "x" 
WHERE p.GedetecteerdeTaal is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would be syntactically correct if you remove the `p.` qualifier from the updated columns in the `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE Tbl_RawDataPART 
SET p.MessageClean = w.Vertaling, p.GedetecteerdeTaal = w.Taal
FROM Tbl_RawDataPART as p
INNER JOIN Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen as w ON p.message = w.Woord 
WHERE p.GedetecteerdeTaal  Is Null;
```

But, I believe that you don't need the extra join to `Tbl_RawDataPART`.
This is how you write a *join-like* `UPDATE` statement with the [`UPATE...FROM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax in SQLite:

```
UPDATE Tbl_RawDataPART AS p
SET MessageClean = w.Vertaling, 
    GedetecteerdeTaal = w.Taal
FROM Tbl_WoordenNietVertalen AS w 
WHERE w.Woord = p.message AND p.GedetecteerdeTaal IS NULL;
```